# Bind Property to Custom List Item

Tags: qooxdoo

I created a Custom ListItem, which has some ChildWidgets. One of these is a Combobox Widget.

I want to set the Model by a Controller, for this I used `qx.data.controller.List`.

With the bindItem and `controller.bindProperty("", "model", null, item, index);` I bind my Model to the List.

My Problem is, that I have one Property in my Model (`text`) which should be binded to the Combobox Value Property.

I tried `controller.bindProperty("text", "value", null, item.getChildControl("combobox"), index);` but I didn't get it to work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please can you create a playground example that demonstrates your problem using http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/playground/ ?  This allows other people to quickly see the exact problem and demonstrate fixes specific to your code.

Comment: I tried to build one, but i didn't get it work. I hope you can see what i want to achieve anyway. tinyurl.com/jjybff7

Comment: I changed it a bit. I want to use my own Properties, not just the model ones, so i can listen to change Events. I also want to listen to the changeSelection event of the controller. This works, but i the data in the listener is always `null`. Here is the updated Playground: tinyurl.com/zynyyhq

Comment: Again i updated the playground. The last thin why it didn't work is that the add function of `this.getRoot()` seems not to exist. tinyurl.com/zhqaj5o

Comment: Please see tinyurl.com/hfxvdbx  The reason that `this.getRoot()` was failing was because you'd switched onto the "Mobile" tab at the top; the other problem was the appearance was set to "listitem", but the "listitem" appearance expects properties like "gap" to exist, so in this demo I've removed the appearance for now.  The other issue was that you can only bind Qooxdoo objects - that means that your `dataRaw` variable is not suitable - I've used the marshalling to turn it into an array of Qooxdoo objects

Comment: Thank you so much. I got iritating because at http://www.qooxdoo.org/current/api/#qx.data.controller.List that only `qx.data.Array` do work. I also tried it one time with the marshaller but it seems that i did something else wrong. One last thing: Is it possible to remove ListItem from List by itself? I tried it with destroy, but it didn't removed it from the Model. I adapted the Playground: tinyurl.com/j5bu4pp

Comment: See below for the full answer; the solution is to not try to remove and dispose of the `CustomListItem` yourself, because the `qx.data.controller.List` is managing that list of widgets itself.  Instead, you remove the item from the model array that the `CustomListItem` is bound to, and the controller detects that and then makes the UI match the model

Comment: That works well for me until i use the Reverse Binding. When i Add new Items and delete the first one, all other will get the Values of the deletet one. I appreciate your help and hope you can help me again. tinyurl.com/zh92bak

Comment: That works for me - please see the updated code that incorporates a slightly modified version of your "Add Item" button.  These comments are becoming a bit like a chat - which is fine, but the best place to chat is on Gitter on the Qooxdoo channel: https://gitter.im/qooxdoo/qooxdoo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the final answer to your question, including the ability to delete items:

```js
qx.Class.define("CustomListItem", {
    extend: qx.ui.core.Widget,
    include: [qx.ui.form.MModelProperty],

    properties: {
        isDistribution: {
            init: true,
            check: "Boolean",
            event: "distributionChange"
        },
        isFilter: {
            init: false,
            check: "Boolean",
            event: "symbolEvent"
        },
        isColumn: {
            init: false,
            check: "Boolean",
            event: "symbolEvent"
        },
        isRow: {
            init: false,
            check: "Boolean",
            event: "changeRow"
        },
        isFilterPatientCases: {
            init: true,
            check: "Boolean",
            event: "symbolEvent"
        },
        isShow: {
            init: true,
            check: "Boolean",
            event: "symbolEvent"
        },
        isUnkownFilter: {
            init: true,
            check: "Boolean",
            event: "symbolEvent"
        },
        value: {
            init: "",
            event: "changeValue"
        }
    },

    members: {
        _createChildControlImpl: function(id) {
            var control;

            switch (id) {
                case "alertimage":
                    control = new qx.ui.basic.Image();
                    control.setWidth(16);
                    this._add(control);
                    break;
                case "suchecombobox":
                    control = new qx.ui.form.ComboBox();
                    this._add(control, {
                        flex: 1
                    });
                    break;
                case "deletebutton":
                    control = new qx.ui.form.Button("Del");
                    control.setMaxWidth(40);
                    this._add(control);
                    break;
                case "imagecomposite":
                    control = new qx.ui.container.Composite(new qx.ui.layout.HBox(0));
                    this._add(control);
                    break;
            }

            return control || this.base(arguments, id);
        }
    },

    construct: function() {
        this.base(arguments);

        this._setLayout(new qx.ui.layout.HBox(0));

        this._showImage = new qx.ui.basic.Image();
        this._showImage.setMaxHeight(25);
        this._showImage.setMaxWidth(25);
        this._showImage.setScale(true);

        this._filterImage = new qx.ui.basic.Image();
        this._filterImage.setMaxHeight(25);
        this._filterImage.setMaxWidth(25);
        this._filterImage.setScale(true);

        this._createChildControl("alertimage");
        this._createChildControl("suchecombobox");
        this._createChildControl("imagecomposite");
        this._createChildControl("deletebutton");

        this.getChildControl("deletebutton").addListener("execute", function(e) {
            var itemModel = this.getModel();
            data.remove(itemModel);
        }, this);

    }

});

var dataRaw = {
    isColumn: false,
    isFilter: false,
    isFilterPatientCases: true,
    isRow: true,
    isShow: true,
    isUnkownFilter: true,
    position: "row",
    queryText: "Dia:I50_:_Herzinsuffizienz",
    textType: ""

};
var data = qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel([dataRaw]);

var list = new qx.ui.form.List();
list.setWidth(200);
var listController = new qx.data.controller.List(null, list);

listController.setDelegate({
    bindItem: function(controller, item, index) {
        controller.bindProperty("", "model", null, item, index);
        controller.bindProperty("queryText", "value", null, item.getChildControl("suchecombobox"), index);
        controller.bindProperty("isFilter", "isFilter", null, item, index);
        controller.bindProperty("isColumn", "isColumn", null, item, index);
        controller.bindProperty("isRow", "isRow", null, item, index);
        controller.bindProperty("isFilterPatientCases", "isFilterPatientCases", null, item, index);
        controller.bindProperty("isShow", "isShow", null, item, index);
        controller.bindProperty("isUnkownFilter", "isUnkownFilter", null, item, index);
        controller.bindProperty("queryText", "value", null, item, index);


    },
    createItem: function() {
        return new CustomListItem();
    }
});

listController.setModel(data);

listController.addListener("changeSelection", function(e) {
    console.log(e.getData().toArray());
}, this);

var doc = this.getRoot();

var button = new qx.ui.form.Button("AddItem");
var newIndex = 1;
button.addListener("execute", function(e) {
    dataRaw.queryText = "New (" + (newIndex++) + ")";
    data.append(qx.data.marshal.Json.createModel([dataRaw]));
}, this);

doc.add(list, {
    left: 0,
    top: 0
});

doc.add(button, {
    left: 200,
    top: 0
});
```

Comment: Don't know if i should open a now Thread, but the context is the same. Is it possible to set the Listitem selected, if i click in the combobox?

Comment: It's a similar thing - you change the controller's `selected` property (it's an instance of `qx.data.Array`) to include the model item, and the controller will update the UI.  Actually, if you have the `CustomListItem` instance and modify the `qx.ui.form.List.selected` property to include it, then the controller will also make sure that it's `selected` property is updated with the correct model, so it's bi-directional